# How to decorate current state resolve function in UI-Router? Current function isn't invoked

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-decorator

I'm trying to DRY in `$stateProvider` and prevent adding the same `auth` function in each resolve. I've created decorator that in each state change would add this function to current state, but `auth` function isn't invoked, How to fix it or how to workaround discussed issue?

```
app.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $provide) {
  $provide.decorator('$state', function($delegate, $rootScope) {
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, state, params) {
      if ($delegate.current === "login" || $delegate.current === "register") {
        return;
      }
      console.log("decorator", $delegate);
      $delegate.current.resolve = {
        auth: ['AuthService', '$stateParams', function(AuthService, $stateParams) {
          //how to invoke this function?
          if (AuthService.isAuthenticated()) {
            return AuthService.me(); //promise
          } else {
            return false;
          }
        }]
      };
    });
    return $delegate;
  });
```

states definition:

```
  $stateProvider.state('root', {
    abstract: true,
    url: '/',
    views: {
      "": {
        controller: 'RootCtrl',
        templateUrl: 'views/root.html'
      },
      "header@root": {
        templateUrl: 'views/header.html'
      }
    }
  })
  .state('root.home', {
    url: urlPrefix,
    views: {
      "content@artworks": {
        templateUrl: 'views/home.html',
        //resolve: {
        //  auth: ['AuthService', '$stateParams', function(AuthService, $stateParams) {
        //  }]
        //}
      }
    }
  })
  ...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand your requirement correctly, we can use native `UI-Router` built-in **`decorator`**:

#### [`decorator(name, func)`](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$stateProvider#methods_decorator)

> Allows you to extend (carefully) or override (at your own peril) the stateBuilder object used internally by $stateProvider. This can be used to add custom functionality to ui-router, for example inferring templateUrl based on the state name... *(read [more in the doc](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$stateProvider#methods_decorator))*

There is [a working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/GfndSzilwVsjhxoinyLo?p=preview)

So, we can have this **`var auth`**

```
var auth = ['AuthService', '$stateParams',
  function(AuthService, $stateParams) {
    //how to invoke this function on needed states?
    if (AuthService.isAuthenticated()) {
      return AuthService.me();
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
];
```

And here we just use decorator with some "IF" logic

```
.config(['$stateProvider', 
  function($stateProvider) {

    $stateProvider.decorator('views', function(state, parent) {
      var result = {},
        views = parent(state);

      // some naive example when to not inject resolve
      if (state.name === "home") { 
        return views;
      }
      // child already has that in parent
      if (state.name.indexOf(".") > 0) { 
        return views;
      }

      angular.forEach(views, function(config, name) {

        // here inject the resolve (if not existing)
        config.resolve = config.resolve || {};
        // and extend it with the auth stuff above
        config.resolve.auth = auth;

        result[name] = config;
      });

      return result;
    });

  }
])
```

And later few our states, which will be extended by the above stuff

```
$stateProvider
    .state('home', {
      url: "/home",
      templateUrl: 'tpl.html',
    })
    .state('parent', {
      url: "/parent",
      templateUrl: 'tpl.html',
      controller: 'SharedCtrl',
    })
    .state('parent.child', {
      url: "/child",
      templateUrl: 'tpl.html',
      controller: 'SharedCtrl',
    });
```

Check it in action [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/GfndSzilwVsjhxoinyLo?p=preview)

Comment: I experience this is not working if you configure the states before adjusting the provider. In my setup i define the states in submodules the app depends on and therefore they are configured before the main app config is able to adjust the state building process.
But this can be solved by moving the state builder config into the first submodule required in that way it will be applied before other submodules are loaded. Hope that help somebody experiencing similar behavior.

Comment: @AirBorne04 -  Good point, I thought it is clear from example... But thanks

Comment: Also doesn't seem to work if you have multiple modules set up with each module declaring its own config - https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/1544

Answer (score 1):

I realized that `$delegate.current` object contains only raw stateProvider config data. To wrap resolve function I add my function to `$delegate.$current` on each state change.

```
$provide.decorator('$state', function($delegate, $rootScope) {
  $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, state, params) {
    if ($delegate.current === "err404" || $delegate.current === "login" || $delegate.current === "register") {
      return;
    }
    console.log("decorator", $delegate);
    $delegate.$current.resolve["auth"] = ['AuthService', '$stateParams', function(AuthService, $stateParams) {
      if (AuthService.isAuthenticated()) {
        console.log('AuthService.me()');
        return AuthService.me();
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    }]
  });
  return $delegate;
});
```

**Update**

I found related discussion on [github](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/1165), you can add universal resolve function into `toState` param:

```
app.run(['$rootScope', '$state',
  function($rootScope, $state) {

    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState) {

      if (toState.name === "login" || toState.name === "register") {
        return;
      }

      toState["resolve"]["auth"] = ['AuthService', '$stateParams', function(AuthService, $stateParams) {
        if (AuthService.isAuthenticated()) {
          return AuthService.me();
        } else {
          return false;
        }
      }];
    });
  }
]);
```