# Is it possible to have ui-views for non-nested states?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-ui, state

Say I've got `state1` which has children `state1.child1` and `state2.child2`.  There's also `state2` which has `state2.child1` and `state2.child2`.  Is there any way I can put a `ui-view` in `state1.child1` to view `state2.child1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is **no** *(as most likely expected)*.

States are hierarchical, and the same applies to their views. So, we cannot display child of one hierarchy in another's hierarchy parent.

In case, we just wanted to reduce amount of code (declaring same views and substates in different hierarchies) we can use e.g. some decorators:

- [AngularJS: How to set one state as a global parent in UI-Router (to use modal as common parts)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32085689/1679310)
- [Setting view's name from decorator - Angular Ui Router](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33112912/1679310)

Comment: Yeah, that's kind of what I expected.  I've got a view/state that I wanted to be able to reuse in three-ish different places, but maybe it would make more sense to remake it as a directive instead.  Although your solutions look good too.  Thanks!

Comment: Great if that could help anyhow ;) Enjoy mighty UI-Router

Comment: Thanks!  I have been for a few months. I've only been using Angular in general since July, but I'm loving it.